# Unable to connect @IBSegueAction

Tags: segue, uistoryboard, xcode11, ios13, ibsegueaction

I have single view controller with a `UIButton` containing the following code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
    }
    
    
    @IBSegueAction
    func makeAnotherController(coder: NSCoder, sender: Any?, segueIdentifier: String?) -> ViewController? {
        return ViewController(coder: coder)
    }
}
```

According to [Apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_11_beta_release_notes?changes=latest_min_4_10&language=objc), this is the correct signature for a `@IBSegueAction`, and it compiles OK, but I'm unable to connect the button to the `@IBSegueAction` by dragging from the storyboard scene to the assistant editor.

I can connect without issue to other outlets or actions.

Any thoughts? Xcode 11 bug or am I doing something wrong?

---

*Update*

Briefly, Apple's docs say…

> Create a connection from a segue to an @IBSegueAction method on its source view controller. On new OS versions that support Segue Actions, that method will be called … An IBSegueAction method takes up to three parameters: a coder, the sender, and the segue’s identifier. The first parameter is required, and the other parameters can be omitted from your method’s signature if desired

I'm unable to complete the first step (create a connection)

Comment: Sounds like a bug - do you still have the issue in the latest version of XCode?

Answer (score 2):

This was my misunderstanding of Apple's docs. When they say…

> Create a connection from a segue to an @IBSegueAction method on its source view controller.

they *literally* mean drag from the line that represents the segue to the view controller.